# Вывести данные в 4 блока из массива объектов на нативном JS

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. У меня есть массив из 4 объектов, нужно их вывести в html.

```
<div class="sphere sphere--1">
    <span class="sphere__text"></span>
    <img class="sphere__img" src="" alt="">
</div>
<div class="sphere sphere--2">
    <span class="sphere__text"></span>
    <img class="sphere__img" src="" alt="">
</div>
<div class="sphere sphere--3">
    <span class="sphere__text"></span>
    <img class="sphere__img" src="" alt="">
</div>
<div class="sphere sphere--4">
    <span class="sphere__text"></span>
    <img class="sphere__img" src="" alt="">
</div>
```

```
function printLastSlideContent(gamePage, index) {
  const slideSections = [...gamePage.querySelectorAll('#innerGameSwiper .section')];
  const sphere = [...slideSections[index].querySelectorAll('.sphere')];

  sphere.map(item => {
    const name = item.querySelector('.sphere__text');
    const img = item.querySelector('.sphere__img');

    finalCategories.map(data => {
      item.setAttribute('id', data.id);
      name.textContent = data.name;
      img.setAttribute('src', data.img);
    })
  });
}
```

Пояснение: **finalCategories** это массив из 4 объектов, содержимое которого нужно добавить в span и img.

Функция отрабатывает коряво, добавляются данные только из одного объекта во все 4 html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const finalCategories = [{id:1,"img":"https://www.logaster.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/0127.png"},{id:2,"img":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e5/NASA_logo.svg/200px-NASA_logo.svg.png"},{id:3,"img":"https://static.rfstat.com/renderforest/images/v2/logo-homepage/flat_3.png"},{id:4,"img":"https://delo.ua/files/news/images/3644/62/picture2_v-google-maps-poj_364462_p0.png"}]

function printLastSlideContent() {
  // const slideSections = [...gamePage.querySelectorAll('#innerGameSwiper .section')];
  const sphere = [...document.querySelectorAll('.sphere')];

  sphere.map((item, index) => {
    const name = item.querySelector('.sphere__text');
    const img = item.querySelector('.sphere__img');
    let data = finalCategories[index];
    name.setAttribute('id', data.id);
    img.setAttribute('src', data.img);
  });
}

printLastSlideContent();
```

```css
.sphere img {
  heigth:200xp;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sphere sphere--1">
    <span class="sphere__text"></span>
    <img class="sphere__img" src="" alt="">
</div>
<div class="sphere sphere--2">
    <span class="sphere__text"></span>
    <img class="sphere__img" src="" alt="">
</div>
<div class="sphere sphere--3">
    <span class="sphere__text"></span>
    <img class="sphere__img" src="" alt="">
</div>
<div class="sphere sphere--4">
    <span class="sphere__text"></span>
    <img class="sphere__img" src="" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, это оказывается было так просто. К вечеру голова вообще не соображает) Еще раз спасибо)